# How to make anchor tag responsive using bootstrap when it has long text and long text with image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to make design responsive to all web and devices. try to keep  first link button all the way to the left(annoucing document stuff button) and other button to all the way right. it gets break for small device. try also wrapping anchor text but not working. please advice.is it possible to achieve it though bootstrap only? if not what custom style i need to make please advice. i can't use jquery.

[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/bUrcCEm8htMkk1nLnxx9?p=preview)

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
     One way 
    <div class="panel panel-body col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding pull-left">
        <a class="btn btn-default">Annoucing Notification document(anc)</a>  
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-default">Remove stuff</a> 
      </div>
    </div><br />
    another issue when it has image <br/>
    <div class="well col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-padding">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 no-padding">
        <a class="btn btn-default">Annoucing Notification document(anc)</a>  
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 no-padding col-lg-push-3">
        <a class="btn btn-default"><img id = "img_and" class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGvUXEzMLx4-3F37e89TwVwdRt7wE1F79nMiT_Z7sPOZdk6RzC" style = "width:15pt">Remove stuff</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

css

```
anch{
  word-wrap : break-word;
}

#img_and{
  width:5pt;
  height : 15pt;
  vertical-align:top;

}
```

This is how i would like to make it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `class="text-right"` to the remove button container, something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding pull-right text-right">
    <a class="btn btn-default">Remove stuff</a> 
</div>
```

And also use the break points of each class, when the two buttons are collapsing u could add a "col-xs-12" on the buttons containers so they start in a diferent line.

If you can add a simple draw of the layout you want it's going to be easier to help... difficult to visualize without a draw :/

**UPDATE**

For the icon inside the button, it's always a better practice to use a background image instead on an image on the html.

[HERE YOU CAN SEE A LIVE EXAMPLE.](https://jsfiddle.net/juanmamig/kLmv0q1e/) You will have to use media queries for your responsive buttons.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i have add draw for visualization. want to display it like that. two button should be always align. i dont want it in different line when it collapsed.